# Why might my tailwindcss font sizes be innacurate in edge/chrome

Tags: tailwind-css

I'm setting my font size with text-7xl which should be 72px but it comes out as 81px

When I set it to 6xl it comes out as 67.5 although it should be 64.

Similar things happen with padding. Any ideas why this could happen?

```
<div class="text-7xl"> Hello </div>
<div class="text-6xl"> This is larger than expected </div>
```

Comment: Please show some css/html code that is a [mre] of your problem. (a.k.a. Help us to help you, by providing a simple example of the problem you are facing)

Comment: It really is an oddity. Perhaps others have encountered this.

Comment: Input is needed. see yellow marked pieces (4 yellow marked pieces):  https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Fp4l.png

Answer (score 0):

When I am using this HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
     <title>Some comparison test for tailwind</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div style="font-size: 72px;"> Helllo </div>
      <div style="font-size: 64px;"> This is larger than expected </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And compare it to: https://play.tailwindcss.com/9lhx4IwBy3

I do have a hard time to understand your conclusion...

I only see a different font is being used, but size (height, Edge text is showing slight wider) seems to be the same?

[image: Tailwind]

compared to: Edge:
[image: Edge]

Comment: O, crap, and I have a typo on the picture.... 

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. The HTML tag had text-lg as a class which caused everything underneath it to have a different font-size.